# I want to use countif function to get the count of total devices on each ID i have applied the formula but no answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

[image: Data image]

I want to use `COUNTIF()` function to get the count of total devices on each ID i have applied the formula but no answer.

Refer to attach image for data.

Comment: It should be like this --> `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$22,A2)` and fill down, and if you are using `MS365` then `=COUNTIF(A2:A22,A2:A22)` or if it has to be based on both the columns then `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$22,A2,B$2:B$22,B$2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$22,A2)
```

...will count, for each ID, how many times it occurs in the list. This assumes that you can be sure that the Device field is unique for each ID - i.e. you have no duplicate rows.

If you do, or may, have duplicates, you will need to test on both columns:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$22,A2,B$2:B$22,B2)
```